Sporadically CORS Error while attempting to send the request to Azure Function: "Access to fetch at '***' has been blocked by CORS policy"
I have an Azure Functions deployed to Azure to TEST and PROD env. It is Isolated Worker model. I am sendint request while Azure Front Door.
This is deployment script:
resource runApiApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-03-01' = {
  tags: tags
  name: runApiFunctionName // this is parameter from upper level
  location: location // this is parameter from upper level value is 'canadacentral'
  kind: 'functionapp'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentity.id}': {} 
    }
  }
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: servicePlan.id
    httpsOnly: true
    enabled: true
    reserved: false
    siteConfig: {
      use32BitWorkerProcess: false
      netFrameworkVersion: 'v8.0'
      minTlsVersion: '1.2'
      ftpsState: 'Disabled'
      http20Enabled: true
      localMySqlEnabled: false
      alwaysOn: true
      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'
          value: applicationInsightsKey
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE'
          value: '1'
        }
        {
          name: 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT'
          value: aspenv
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsStorage'
          value: storageAccountConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsDisableHomepage'
          value: 'true'
        }
        {
          name: 'AzureWebJobsDotNetReleaseCompilation'
          value: 'true'
        }
        {
          name: 'WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING'
          value: storageAccountConnectionString
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'
          value: 'dotnet-isolated'
        }
        {
          name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION'
          value: '~4'
        }
        // and other connection string etc.
      ]
      connectionStrings: [
        // my configuration
      ]
      cors: {
        allowedOrigins: ["https://mySiteWhereItIsDeployedForUI",
          "https://functions.azure.com",
          "https://functions-staging.azure.com",
          "https://functions-next.azure.com",
          "http://localhost:9000"] // my UI
      }
    }
  }
} 

Production team works from England and they don't face this issue at all, but development/testing team is located in different countries: Poland, Ukraine, Armenia, Spain for instance and sometimes sporadically while sending the request from UI this issue occurred.
For example -> POST Request from UI to the Azure Function executed three times. The first one at 22:01, the second one at 22:15, the third one at 22:29. As a result the first one is successfully executed, the next two failed.
This is JS/TS code of fetch I am using to send a request:
export const fetchRaw = async (
    url: string,
    options?: FetchOptions,
) => {
    options = {
        mode: 'cors',
        method: 'POST', 
        body: bodyData, 
        ignoreError: true,
    };
    let headers = options.headers;
    if (!(headers instanceof Headers)) {
        headers = new Headers(options.headers);
    }

    const jwt = window.localStorage.getItem(JWT_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY);
    headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${jwt}`);
    if (options.body && typeof options.body !== 'string' && !(options.body instanceof FormData)) {
        options.body = JSON.stringify(options.body);
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
    options.headers = headers;
    const response = await fetch(url, options);
    if (!response.ok) {
        // redirect logic and etc, no matters for now
    }
    const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
    if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('application/json') === 0) {
        return response.json(); // <---- The result of server(CORS) error is HERE
    } else if (contentType && contentType.indexOf('text/plain') === 0) {
        return response.text();
    } else {
        return response;
    };
};

Browser errors in console:
 { 
    "Message": "https://myProject-qa.com/#/ - Access to fetch at 'https://api-qa.com/api/canada/projects' from origin 'https://myProject-qa.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled." 
  }, 
  {
    "Level": 4, 
    "Message": "https://api-qa.com/api/canada/projects - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED" 

  }, 
  { 
    "Level": 4, 
    "Message": "https://myProject-qa.com/app/index.6354247a.js 0:405147 Uncaught TypeError: e.json is not a function" 
  }, 

What I tried:

Well, I checked the whole configuration again related to CORS: everything is assigned fine(like in .bicep) for all my env
I googled up this issue, but everything points to CORS configuration in Function App, but it is fine! The ugly this that this error is sporadically and depends on location!

As a solution of course is adding retry pattern to UI, but I don't like this solution and would like to get to the bottom of the situation. Thanks
